How to check the rabbitmq connection health with masstransit
I´m using masstransit to talk to my rabbitmq service. The task i m trying to achieve is a periodical check on the connection to the rabbitmq service via masstransit.
What i tried and achieved so far:

I´m using the IBusControl.CheckHealth() to accquire the status of the masstransit Bus. Howerver if the connection is forcibly closed (for example by the rabbitmq managment plugin) the health status is unchanged (still showing healthy)

I´m using a rabbitmq client to check if i can connect to the service.
This allows me to check if the rabbitmq is reachable, but not if the
connection that is used by masstransit is healthy.


So what do i have to do to check the connection that is used by
masstransit to exchange messages with rabbitmq?
Exposing a
healthcheck endpoint in asp.net core is not what i want. I want to
check the status within the same application where masstransit is
configured.
The configuration
 .AddMassTransit( x => {
 string? rabbitMqConnectionString = LoadConnectionstring();
 (string username, string password, string host, ushort port) = ParseRabbitMqConnectionString( rabbitMqConnectionString );

     bool isDevelopmentEnvironment = true; // we assume we are starting from debug

     x.UsingRabbitMq( ( context, cfg ) => {
         cfg.Host( host, (ushort)port, "/", h => {
             h.Username( username );
             h.Password( password );

             if( isDevelopmentEnvironment )
             {
                 h.RequestedConnectionTimeout( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 ) );
             }
         } );

         if( isDevelopmentEnvironment )
         {
             // Konfiguriere die Anzahl der Verbindungsversuche
             cfg.UseMessageRetry( retryConfig => {
                 retryConfig.None();
             } );
         }
     } );
 }

Hope y'all can help me out here.

If you close the connection, MassTransit reconnects. So it would be back to healthy as soon as the closed connection is discovered.

@ChrisPatterson please take a look at the code i posted. I set retries to none. That would mean masstransit is not reconnection am I right?

Message retry has nothing to do with RabbitMQ connection management – which is not configurable.

@ChrisPatterson Im effectivly not sending a message. I just let masstransit connect to rabbitmq, after that i forcibly close the connection or turn off the rabbitmq service. Now the connection remains healthy even though it is nor possible. Maybe until a new message (with exception) is sent?

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2159

I wrote "Exposing a healthcheck endpoint in asp.net core is not what i want". The github issue u refering checks the health state via a aps net core health endpoint

The solution I ended up using is to create a reciever endpoint with:
      // used to supervise if the rabbitmq connection is healthy
      cfg.ReceiveEndpoint( "test-queue", e => {
            e.UseMessageRetry( r => r.None() );
            e.Consumer<HealthMessageConsumer>();
      } );

And then sending the request periodical to check wethever the connection with rabbitmq is stable
    private async Task<bool> SendHealthMessage()
    {
        try
        {
            ISendEndpoint endpoint = await busControl.GetSendEndpoint( new Uri( "rabbitmq://<host>/test-queue" ) );
            await endpoint.Send( new HealthMessage(), new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 3 ) ).Token );

            return true; // Connection is healthy
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            // Catch any exceptions related to RabbitMQ connection issues
            Log.Error( $"Error sending test message: {ex.Message}", ex );
            return false; // Connection failed
        }
    }

Note: use a cancellation token because if the message failed to send it gets hung up at the await send
To Be honest this is a workaround, but it works for me. Im kinda confused why masstransit makes it so difficult to check for the rabbitmq connection, hopefully in later version they make it more clear on how to achieve this.
